# Carousel flip web vs mobile

Tags: javascript, drupal, conditional-statements, carousel, admin

I need to write code in a old Drupal content Source coding (I mean in the actual website admin content)... which mean I can't use modules nor extensions (Too old AND using bootstrap 4 theme).
Last month, I built a carousel with horizontal pics. NOW... The customer ask for keeping those horozontal pictures when somebody watch the original web version of the site AND/BUT he now gave me vertical pictures to create the same carousel, but to appear vertically when in mobile version.

SOOOO... I must create a condition INSIDE the content Source code saying that IF it is original web site dimensions, use Horizonral pics ELSE (If it is watched in mobile version) use Vertical pics.
Old Drupal using bootstrap is so hard to manipulate .. I bet I have to create a  tag but it's not that simple... I already tried I bunch of stuff without success...
Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.